# Instagram Android Share Intent: Unable to load image

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm facing an issue sending a share intent to Instagram on Android, from the last update from 3 days ago. This is on an Ionic app

I can reproduce the error in the following conditions:

- Android >= 8
- Last Instagram Version (133.0.0.32.120)
- Only sharing to Feed, Stories read the image as expected

I will not add the code I'm using to share because seems to be another thing, some change that Instagram introduced in the last update, maybe permissions or something else.

I discard the image path (read/write) because for Stories it's working fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm still try to find a solution. Meanwhile, if you are having the same issue, please leave a comment on this Facebook Bug ticket

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/

**EDIT 2**

This is a workaround solution, I think this is an Instagram bug and should be working again soon, but meanwhile, you can share to Instagram Feed using the `MediaStore`. I tested this solution on Android 6 to 10.

```
// Save image to gallery
String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        getContentResolver(),
        mediaPath,
        "My image",
        "My super image description"
);

// Parse the gallery image url to uri
Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(savedImageURL);

ClipData clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("Image", savedImageURI);

shareIntent.setClipData(clipData);
```

To make it work correctly, you will need to ask `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I handled this part on Ionic side

Comment: I am also seeing the exact same thing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet! please share the solution if you find it :)

Comment: I sent an email to their support email listed on the play store. Might want to do the same so we get them to take note.

Comment: Yes, already sent an email few hs ago.. @Ari

Comment: @mauriblint any info on this?

Comment: nothing yet.. seems to be a IG bug, I'm trying to make it work but for Stories works fine.. @Alin

Comment: @Alin IG realease a new version for Android, could you check please if is now working for you?

Comment: The update is not showing up to me, maybe it's rolling out progressively. Is it working on your end? Thanks.

Comment: 134.0.0.26.121 version has the same issue. i have a flutter application and it was working so fine. now its not working. getting the same issue. any solution?

Comment: Hi, not yet, I'm still working on it :/ a lot of apps stop working, I found issues in a lot of repos, like Lightroom from adobe, not working also, and more.. @vitralyoz

Comment: yes i have instagram repost app reposthem and it has the same problem? what do you think about that? ig bug?

Comment: hi @vitralyoz, please leave a comment on this facebook bug ticket https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/

Comment: hi @Alin, please leave a comment on this facebook bug ticket https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/

Comment: Hello guys, I just update the question with a workaround solution, it is working for me

Comment: @mauriblint i tried your solution. It gives error. Whats is your mediaPath ? MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content://media/external/images/media; expected MIME type under image/*

Comment: Hi @jancooth you will need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, i handle this part on Ionic, but maybe you need to check and ask this before same the image

Comment: Hi @mauriblint what is the main idea for your solution. i develop the app with flutter. do you save image to phone then share? or can you explain the difference between your first code and now.

Comment: Hi @vitralyoz, in my previous code I used the FileProvider, that is not working right now, I save the images on the app cache folder. With this fix, yo will save the image on the gallery using the MediaStore, and get the path to that images using the same module. And this is working

Comment: Thank you. I did the same thing. I save the image to phone i got the path and set the clipdata and the result is the same. Unable to load image :( i am waiting the instagram. I wish they solve this. Whatsapp also nor working sharing image to ins. Feed.

Comment: I wonder how you initialize "shareIntent"

Comment: Problem solved with latest instagram update

Comment: It started working fine after the latest Instagram update but today I started receiving some user complaints again. Anybody else seeing the same thing?

Comment: facing same issue kindly tell if somebody find solution for it